# Spinner onItemSelectedListener inside a fragment isn't working properly

Tags: android, kotlin

Using a spinner on a fragment, all seems to be good, but when I add an EditText and set focus in EditText, my spinner listener won't respond...

I have tried a lot of things, like change my spinner data, delete all the disruptive code, change layouts.

```xml
<FrameLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/button_orange"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/spinnerCountries"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/white"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="@color/orange">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_phone_number"
                    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/icon_help_phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" android:background="@null" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

```java
mSpinnerCountries!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>, arg1: View, position: Int, arg3: Long) {
                prefs!!["country_position"] = position
                val mSelectedCountry = arg0.selectedItem as Pays?

                prefs!!["user_countrycode"] = mSelectedCountry?.code
                prefs!!["carrier_countryiso"] = mSelectedCountry?.iso
                prefs!!["country_prefix"] = mSelectedCountry?.prefix

                Timber.d("Item selected on spinner : code ${mSelectedCountry?.code}, iso ${mSelectedCountry?.iso}, prefix ${mSelectedCountry?.prefix}")
                mEditText!!.text!!.clear()
                mEditText!!.text!!.clearSpans()
                mEditText!!.setText(mSelectedCountry?.prefix)
                mEditText!!.setSelection(mSelectedCountry?.prefix!!.length)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {
                val mSelectedCountry = arg0.selectedItem as Pays?
                prefs!!["user_countrycode"] = mSelectedCountry?.code
                prefs!!["carrier_countryiso"] = mSelectedCountry?.iso
                prefs!!["country_prefix"] = mSelectedCountry?.prefix

                Timber.d("No Item selected on spinner : code ${mSelectedCountry?.code}, iso ${mSelectedCountry?.iso}, prefix ${mSelectedCountry?.prefix}")
                mEditText!!.setText(mSelectedCountry?.prefix)
                mEditText!!.setSelection(mSelectedCountry?.prefix!!.length+1)
            }
        }
```

Now I expect to be able to use the spinner listener even after the edited text has been focused.

Comment: What do you mean by "I make the focus on it", you're doing it programmatically or by touching? Please, check if steps are correct to reproduce? 1) Click on the spinner select and item 2) Then touch on `EditText` and `EditText` gains focus 3) Now again click on the spinner but spinner won't open. Are those steps what you're doing?

Comment: What is the root `ViewGroup` in that layout? `FrameLayout` will just stack its child `View`s, overlapping one atop the other, so if it is another `FrameLayout`, then it would seem that your `Spinner` is being covered by other `View`s. Btw, you have a couple of unnecessary `FrameLayout`s there, as it is.

Comment: @Farid When i said "make the focus on it", it was for a touch on the EditText component. And yes this is the steps to reproduce. I'm using val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_phone, container, false) to inflate the view

Comment: @Farid the last step, I can open my spinner, but it doesn't detect an item selected

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works as expected.

Can you please create a very simple project and add this line to that project and check if everything works properly? If below code works in your simple project we can debug your main project further. If this is not working, then there could be a problem in your device.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/spinnerCountries"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:hint="phone number"
                android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" android:background="@null" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Arrays.asList("a","b","c"))
        spinnerCountries.adapter =adapter

        spinnerCountries!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>, arg1: View, position: Int, arg3: Long) {
                input_phone!!.text!!.clear()
                input_phone!!.text!!.clearSpans()
                input_phone!!.setText(adapter.getItem(position))
                input_phone!!.setSelection(adapter?.getItem(position)!!.length)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {


            }
        }
    }
}
```